# iOS animation with duration and autoreverse

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I am animating an `UIImageView` with the UIView block API. My animation fades the `UIImageView` In and Out continuously. How can I animate this only for a specific time duration ?

I have put up this piece of code

```
float tempDuration = 5.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:tempDuration
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         _imageView.alpha = 1;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

Comment: what about removing the UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse in options

Comment: UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse is to repeat the fade in and out till duration.. i need the imageview to keep fading in and out till 5 seconds with opacity changing every second.

Comment: better make a loop for how many times you want with the @yuvrajsinh answer

Comment: ya set other method for stop animation and call that method as per your requirement completely agree with @ashokdy

Comment: how would i make a loop iterate for 5 seconds...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all allow me to introduce an article that is **awesome** to understand some features of the animations:

[Controlling Animation Timming](http://ronnqvi.st/controlling-animation-timing/)

In this article you have a part that shows what you want.

You want something like this:

[image]

Therefore you can configure that in the following way:

```
-(void) animateImageView:(UIImageView*) imageView 
            withDuration:(int) duration 
         withRepeatCount: (int) repeatCount {

     CABasicAnimation *opacityAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
     opacityAnim.fromValue = @1.0;
     opacityAnim.toValue = @0.0;
     opacityAnim.autoreverses = YES;
     opacityAnim.duration = duration/2.0/repeatCount;
     opacityAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
     opacityAnim.repeatCount = repeatCount;
     [imageView.layer addAnimation:opacityAnim forKey:nil];
 }
```

This way you guarantee that your animation will always be 5 seconds and you can tune in the number of repetitions.

Comment: @AhmedZ. that article is so awesome that it really needs to be shared :). this way is easier to fine tune animation without have to worry about the duration. You can focus on the number of repetitions to tune it :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could try `CABasicAnimation` instead if `[UIView animateWithDiration: ... ]`

it should be something like this:

```
  CABasicAnimation *opacityAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
  opacityAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
  opacityAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
  opacityAnim.autoreverses = YES;
  opacityAnim.duration = duration;
  opacityAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
  opacityAnim.repeatCount = 5;
  [imageView.layer addAnimation:opacityAnim forKey:nil];
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way to do it

Comment: Thank you @iiFreeman for the help.. but Tiago's Solution has really done the trick..

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following changes to do your work.

```
- (void)animateImageView{
    static int animcount = 1;
    float tempDuration = 1.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:tempDuration
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^{
                         self.imgView.alpha = 1;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if(finished && animcount<5){
                             animcount+=1;
                             [self animateImageView];
                         }
                         else if (finished && animcount==5){
                             [self.imgView.layer removeAllAnimations];
                         }

                     }];
}
```

Comment: this will only make the uiimageview fade in and out once.

Comment: tried the code.. its only fading it In and out once.. not my requirements

Comment: What is your exact requirement for animation?

Comment: UIImageView animation keep Fading In and Out every second for 5 seconds... got it?

Comment: Now try the my edited answer and you can change it as per your need.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42646/discussion-between-yuvrajsinh-and-ahmed-z)